# How to make image appear on link hover

Tags: css

I am trying to make a different image appear when hovering over each link

[image: Current situation]

```
    <div class="wrapper">

    <h1>PROJECTS</h1>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="generation.html">GENERATION ANXIETY</a></li>
    <li><a href="glitterboy.html">GLITTER BOY COSMETICS</a></li>
    <li><a href="untitledhuman.html">UNTITLED HUMAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="bodys.html">BODY(S) UNDER NEGOTIATION</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 1;
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 2;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 40;
}

a:hover {
position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
content: url(Anxiety1%20hover.png); /* no need for qoutes */
position: absolute;
right:0;
}
```

I feel like the images need to be in their own div as they are cuurently inside the ul tag but not sure how to make this work

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: haha set class for each link tag, and use different images for hover of each one just like the code u post, quite easy huh ? or what do you really want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Sibling Combinators `~`

A GSC: `~` means that whatever is on the right of `~` is following whatever is on the left side of `~` styles are applied to the right.

**Example**

> ```
>   <a href='#/' class='A'>A</a> 
>   <section class='B'>
>       <article class='C'>C</article>
>   </section>     
>   .A:hover ~ .B .C {color:red}
> ```
>
> If you hover over `.A` then any `.B` that follows and has a `.C` nested within it will have its text turn red.

---

### Demo

```css
main {
  position:relative;
}

figure {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:20vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

img {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  font-size: 10vh;
  width: 5vw;
  margin: 5vh;
}

.l1:hover~figure .one,
.l2:hover~figure .two,
.l3:hover~figure .three {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: 0.5s
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class='item l1'><a href='#/'>ONE</a></div>
<div class='item l2'><a href='#/'>TWO</a></div>
<div class='item l3'><a href='#/'>THREE</a></div>


<figure>
  <img src='https://cdn1.wine-searcher.net/images/labels/27/50/finca-bacara-time-waits-for-no-one-jumilla-spain-11002750t.jpg' class='one'>
  <img src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53221edce4b0ff54eacdae95/53253064e4b0ba32c23fc68c/53253085e4b05db45c4abdda/1395030141683/Table+for+Two15X30.jpg?format=100w' class='two'>
  <img src='http://th06.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2013/037/1/9/under_the_three_moons_by_timidemerald-d5u03xr.jpg' class='three'>
</figure>
</main>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can play around with it. You can have multiple images for each link and show it when hover

```css
ul {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 40;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a:hover {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover+img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>PROJECTS</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="generation.html">GENERATION ANXIETY</a>
      <img class="right hidden" height="200" width="200" src="https://i.imgur.com/0c43ELR.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="glitterboy.html">GLITTER BOY COSMETICS</a>
      <img class="right hidden" height="200" width="200" src="https://i.imgur.com/lBXHfud.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using pseudo element `:after`

```
a:hover:after {
    content: url(imageURL);
    display: block;
}
```